# How does one discuss a closed question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

How does one contest the closing of a question?

How does one submit a request for an edited closed question to be reopened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the first, you ask a question here about it, though if you've edited it to fit the site's standards that's probably unnecessary.

To answer the second, if you've edited a closed question, it automatically gets placed in the reopen queue to be viewed by [people with reopen privileges on this site](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions). If after a few days its not reopened and you feel it should be, flag the post and a moderator will take a look at it.

If the mod declines your flag, but you are still certain that it is on topic and fits within the site's rules and guidelines, you're welcome to open a question on meta and ask why it remains closed.